# Why Symbol.iterator in javascript is used to create iterator?

Tags: javascript, iterator, symbols

What is the concept behind using  `Symbol.iterator` in javascript to create iterators?
Is `Symbol.iterator` just a primitive value of type symbol? Why it is used to create iterators?

Please explain I am confused about it.
I followed the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator) but could not find helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Symbol` was added to the language to provide a way to create unique named objects instead of using strings. This is especially useful when creating object properties so they won't conflict with user-defined properties. These are now used for internal property names used by the language.

In this case, `Symbol.iterator` contains the symbol naming the method used for default iteration over instances of a class. It's basically just a global variable that names that symbol.